# How to get values from Json Array to pass them through intent

Tags: android, json, android-intent

Hey guys i am building an app that loads values from json array to listview. What i am having in the database is some stocks, each stocks has 7 prices. I get the data from the json request like this:

Any help will be welcomed and highly appreciated.

I also get the price and the name to be shown on the list and i have already set the in the textviews above so i wanna populate the list view only with values from price1-price7 can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out:

Sending Activity

```
 public void registerCallClickBack() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            TextView tv1 =(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_name);
            TextView tv2 =(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.stock_price);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StockItem.class);


            intent.putExtra("name", tv1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("price",tv2.getText().toString());

            //passes all you stock info (note you do not need the above 2 lines)
            intent.putExtra("stockInfo", stocksList.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Receiving activity

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stockInfo");
```

Comment: Edited my answer. If there are issues, please post any error logs.

Comment: in the putExtra says its not applicable for the arguments(string, List<Map<String, String>>)

Comment: how am i going to convert this List<HashMap<String, String>> into a string array???

Comment: I think you are going to need a HashMap.  You can pull the data you want from the List and get store it in an array. Something like: `HashMap<String,String> map = stocksList.get(0); String[] values = new String[map.size()];` Then you can set each item of the array such as `values[position] = map.get(KEY value)`. Alternative is after getting the map `ArrayList<String> values = map.values;` Then get the array from the arraylist `values.toArray();`

Comment: I updated to code to send a HashMap to your second activity. There you can use the data to set up the listview.

Comment: The problem is that the your list does not have any data. I think in the method ListData() you creating a local copy of the stocksList and that gets deleted when the method end. Does your main activity have a stocksList variable that you can store this data in?

Comment: no. and this is what i figured out as well. but since the method ListDrawer() is public void and the class JsonReadTask shouldn't i be able to get the methods and the variables in the MainActivity class as well???also i wanna get the values from the stocksList in the JsonReadTast class which is also public.

Comment: No. Any variable declared in a method only exists in that method. If you want one variable to be accessed in multiple methods, you should declare it in the Activity (ie `public class MainActivity extends Activity {private Integer currentLocation; ...` then in all other methods just call it/set it like `currentLocation = ...` without declaring it again. If JsonReadTask is a inner class inside of your MainActivity, then it can access the variable declared for MainActivity

Comment: so what can i do to get those values??

Comment: in you MainActivity declare `List<HashMap<String, String>> stocksList;` And then in your  ListDrawer() method you need to initialize the variable. so in the ListDrawer, `stocksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` and get rid of `List<Map<String, String>> stocksList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();` if you need the variable earlier you may want to initialize in the onCreate method. If you need to refer to this variable, just call it and  do not create a new variable instance of it.

Comment: well i did intent.putExtra("stockInfo", stocksList.get(position));and in the other activity List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  hashMap = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("stockInfo"); and still crashes..

Comment: Well it worked and now i get some sort of weird stuff..i post an image so that you can check this out.

Comment: i believe the problem is the line ` String[] myItems = {hashMap.values().toString()};`. It needs to be  String[] myItems = (String[]) hashMap.values().toArray()`;

Comment: Instead `String[] myItems = (String[]) hashMap.values().toArray();` of try this `ArrayList<String> myitems = hashMap.values();` and pass that in.

Comment: well it crashes and says.
03-21 18:37:10.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1723): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: `ArrayList<String> myitems = new ArrayList<String>(hashMap.values());`

Comment: i got this to working like this
String[] myItems = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[hashMap.size()]);

Comment: The adapter can take either a list or an array. No problem. Glad i could help

Comment: Is there any way to get specific values from that hashMap and not all the values???For example take a look at the image i will post

Comment: Look here for all hashmap methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html. There is a get method to get the value for a certain key.

Comment: i just did 
myItems.remove(name);
myItems.remove(ball);
and it worked...thanks mate cheers...